# Given finite $G\subset O(n)$, is there a "standard" cell structure on $S^{n-1}$ with $G$ acting cellularly?

Tags: finite-groups, discrete-geometry, orthogonal-groups

Let $G\subset O(n)$ be a finite orthogonal group.

> Is there a regular CW-complex structure on $S^{n-1}$ on which $G$ acts cellularly which is in any sense "natural"?

What I'm looking for is inspired by the following examples and ideally would generalize them:

(a) If $G$ is a reflection group, then the Coxeter complex, i.e. the regular CW structure given to $S^{n-1}$ by intersecting with all the reflecting hyperplanes.

(b) If $G$ is $\{\pm I\}$, then the standard cell-complex structure on $S^{n-1}$ with $2$ cells in each dimension from zero up.

(This question is a little soft because I'm not sure how much "naturality" it would be fair to ask for. Candidates include: (1) such that the action on top-dimensional cells is free and transitive [but this seems like it would be too much to hope for]; (2) such that the construction is functorial from the category of subgroups of $O(n)$ with inclusions as morphisms to the category of regular CW-complexes with <strike>cellular embeddings</strike> refinements as morphisms [again, maybe too much to hope for]; (3) a uniform general construction that specializes to both the special cases above. And I'm open to other ideas...)

Comment: Isn't there a cellular action of $O(n)$ on $S^{n-1}$ already? At least, I convinced myself this was true.

Comment: It seems to me that you can have (1) as long as $G$ is non-trivial. And it seems that you can have (2) if you don't demand (1). But you can't have both, even when $n=2$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - I'm not sure what you mean? Since elements of $O(n)$ are arbitrarily small, no cell decomp. of $S^{n-1}$ could be preserved by every element of $O(n)$ - just pick a 0-cell and pick an element of $O(n)$ that perturbs it slightly - what am I missing?

Comment: @TomGoodwillie - I realized later by "cellular embeddings" I really meant refinements, and changed the post correspondingly. For reflection groups, the Coxeter complex has both (1) and (2). Does this change what you're saying? If not, what's the logic?

Comment: If $G$ is a non-cyclic order four subgroup of $O(2)$ then there is only one cell structure satisfying (1). If this is to be a refinement of the cell structure for the order two subgroup of $SO(2)$ then there are only two things that the latter structure can be. But there are lots of those order four subgroups, and they all give different cell structures.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie - got it. Honestly, I would be getting more than I expected to with either (1) or (2) by itself. One thing I want to know is how much it's reasonable to ask for.

Comment: I meant that (I think) there is a cell structure on $O(n)$ such that the map $O(n) \times S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ is cellular, for the standard induced cell structure on the product. If you mean something like "each group element maps a cell to a cell", then this is also cellular, but for the obvious cell structure on a _discrete_ group.

Comment: For cyclic groups, one can pull back a cell structure from a lens space when $n=2m-1$ for some $m$.  This might be an extraordinarily useful question - a $G$ -equivariant cell structure on $S^\infty$ could be obtained if there were a canonical choice of a cell structure on each $S^n$.  Thus one would have $G$-free acyclic chain complex.  This would automatically give a good description of the approximation to the diagonal map on $S^\infty/G$ and maybe, in analogy with the construction of steenrod squares, one would be able to construct stable cohomology operations with coeffficients in $G$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - For what you're saying, do you fix a particular cell structure on $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: @benblumsmith possibly! I can't remember at this point. One should ideally have, after choosing a basepoint on the sphere, the quotient map SO(n) --> S^n cellular, and this helps rigidify things, in the sense that I think the chosen cellular structure on the sphere helps determine the one on the orthogonal group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a first pass at an answer:

Fix a point of the sphere with trivial stabilizer in $G$ and take the Voronoi diagram of its orbit under $G$. The top-dimensional cells are the Voronoi cells, which are polyhedra, and the $d$-dimensional cells are the $d$-faces of these polyhedra.

This construction has property (1) - the action is free and transitive on top-dimensional cells. It does not have property (2). I believe it does have part of property (3) - generalizing the Coxeter complex - since reflecting hyperplanes should be the boundaries of Voronoi cells since the images of the point on either side of a given reflecting hyperplane are equidistant. However, it's unsatisfactory re: the other part of property (3), since I don't see how it constructs lower-dimensional cells (below $n-2$) for the example of $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ acting by the antipodal map.

So, this is an imperfect but passable solution. (Tom Goodwillie shows in a comment that (1) and (2) are not simultaneously possible. More generally, (2) seems kind of ridiculous given how any reasonable cell decomposition for the antipodal map should depend on some arbitrary choice, since this map is central in $O(n)$ so cannot distinguish any points of the sphere. How could such a choice then be made functorial?) But I would be interested in others, so I'll leave the question open for a while.

Comment: you can define the open cells of the Voronoi decompoaition to be the sets where there is not only a unique closest point but also a unique path to that point. Then define the other cells in the unique way extending that. This always works.

Comment: @WillSawin - I don't get this. Take $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acting on $S^2$ antipodally. Pick a point. Its orbit is it plus its antipode. Wlog the north and south poles. Then the voronoi decomposition splits the sphere into north and south hemispheres, with boundary the equator (whether you use "closest point only" or "closest point with unique minimal path"). The 2-cells are clear; but to get 0-cells, I don't see anything that distinguishes any point of the equator from any other, so it seems we have to make another arbitrary choice. Clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow got the antipodal map and the trivial group confused.